Azure: Why can't my frontend app container client make a gRPC request to my backend app container server
Note: My whole application is deployed on Azure, and lives within the same virtual network (vnet1). My application is built with Go and is using gRPC to make requests from the client to the server. The entire flow that I'm testing works when run locally.
The Setup
I'm building a standard web app on Azure. I'm utilizing an Azure MySql database, an app container which is deploying an image for my backend service, another app container which is deploying an image for my frontend service, and a API Gateway which allows public access to my frontend, which lives with the backend and DB within a Virtual Network.
The life cycle of a request therefore could be seen as so (apologies for any poor formatting):

                 *Within a virtual network
                 The API Gateway acts as the public access point*
                 ----------------------------------------------------------------
                |                *within the same container app environment*     |
                |                ----------------------------------------        |
user_browser -> | API Gateway -> | frontendContainer -> backendContainer | -> DB |
                |                ----------------------------------------        |
                 ----------------------------------------------------------------


I do have a wildcard private DNS zone so that my public-facing API Gateway can route requests into my vnet-contained containerApps. This maps azurecontainerapps.io to the static IP address of the containerAppEnvironment, in which both the backend and frontend containers live. This should mean that both APIGateway->Frontend and Frontend->Backend requests should use this DNS listing to route requests based on the container's FullyQualifiedDomainName to the container app environment, and that the port number is then used to route to the correct container/endpoint.
The Problem
TLDR; Why can't my gRPC client in my frontend container successfully make gRPC connections/calls to the gRPC server on my backend container?
My database is up and running. I can validate this by connecting to it remotely through a public access point (I'll clean this up later).
My backendContainer is also up and running, and logs on the container show it's connecting to the DB properly.
The frontendContainer is however not successfully connecting to the backend container, and I cannot figure out why.
The API Gateway is working as expected and the website of the frontendContainer is publicly available as expected.
Both the frontendContainer and backendContainer are within the same app container app environment (containerAppEnv1), and are also within the same virtual network (vnet1). The backend container is exposing port 8080. This is reflected in the docker file for the service, and the backend container's ingress configurations:
az containerapp show --name {name} --resource-group {group_name} --query properties.configuration.ingress --output json
{
  "additionalPortMappings": null,
  "allowInsecure": true,
  "clientCertificateMode": "Ignore",
  "corsPolicy": null,
  "customDomains": null,
  "exposedPort": 0,
  "external": true,
  "fqdn": "{redacted}",
  "ipSecurityRestrictions": null,
  "stickySessions": {
    "affinity": "none"
  },
  "targetPort": 8080,
  "traffic": [
    {
      "latestRevision": true,
      "weight": 100
    }
  ],
  "transport": "Http2"
}

The frontend server is starting up a connection to the backend server upon launch using the backend server's FullyQualifiedDomainName which was given in the above output, with the following code:
// Set up a connection to the backend server.
conn, err := grpc.Dial(cfg.BackendURL, grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("did not connect: %v", err)
}
onboardingClient = onboardingpb.NewOnboardingServiceClient(conn)

The connection doesn't fail on creation time, but the first time I try to make a request with the client, I get the following error:
Error: {"message": "connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp {containerAppEnvironmentStaticIpAddress}:8080: i/o timeout""}

Update: it seems when I try to block on the connection to the backend establishing, it fails and causes a crash looping frontend pod with the following error showing on the web console when I try to make a request to the frontend:
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. retried and the latest reset reason: connection termination

I've been banging my head on this one for a little and can't figure out why the frontend service won't successfully make requests to the backend service, despite have the FQDN and being on the same VNet. I'd really appreciate anyone's help here :)
I've validated that:

the backend container is running
the frontend container is running
both containers are within the same container app environment and vnet
the backend container enabled ingress
the backend container's port 8080 is available, and the app is listening on that port
the frontend app/container is making requests to the container app environment's static IP, and the expected port 8080. My understanding is that this should auto-route to the correct container within the container app environment that is listening on this port.
the entire flow works when run on localhost


Needed to change the backend container from trying an ingress type of HTTP to an ingress type of TCP.
Paired with this code for the backend server startup:
lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
}

server := grpc.NewServer()
    onboardingpb.RegisterOnboardingServiceServer(server, s)

